# Entity Framework cannot map relationship between classes

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance, mapping, table-per-class

I have gone through many posts, but never found a problem similar to mine

For some reason I cannot correctly map relationship between classes while creating database using EF Code First

The classes are - Order abstract class

```
public abstract class Order : IObjectWithState
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    public OrderType Type { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public State ObjectState { get; set; }

    public string CustomerId { get; set; }
}
```

And two classes that implement it:

```
public class SampleOrder : Order
{
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime CompletionDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
    public virtual Address BillAddress { get; set; }
}

public class HideOrder : Order
{
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime CompletionDate { get; set; }
    public bool Paid { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
    public virtual Address BillAddress { get; set; }
}
```

This is Address class:

```
public class Address : IObjectWithState
{
    public int AddressId { get; set; }

    public string AddressLine { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public bool Main { get; set; }
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public State ObjectState { get; set; }
}
```

My context class looks like so:

```
public PhoeniceContext() : base("Phoenice")
{
}

public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
public DbSet<SampleOrder> SampleOrders { get; set; }
public DbSet<HideOrder> HideOrders { get; set; }
public DbSet<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<SampleOrder>().Map(m =>
    {
        m.MapInheritedProperties();
        m.ToTable("SampleOrders");
    });

    modelBuilder.Entity<HideOrder>().Map(m =>
    {
        m.MapInheritedProperties();
        m.ToTable("HideOrders");
    });
}
```

When I try to create the database I get an error saying:

> The association 'SampleOrder_BillAddress' between entity types
>   'SampleOrder' and 'Address' is invalid. In a TPC hierarchy independent
>   associations are only allowed on the most derived types.

If I comment out BillAddress properties from both order classes mapping to OrderItems behaves correctly. Why mapping to Address item doesn't work as well??

Comment: you can use my answer to this question in another post :

http://stackoverflow.com/a/31323735/1244561